# How to hide cookies information in headers in expresscalls for .sendredirect, .send and .sendFile functions? I have used pino logger

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Logger used in the code:
How to hide cookies information in headers in express calls for .sendredirect, .send  and .sendFile functions? I have used pino logger.

**LOGGER.ts**

```
var pinoms = require('pino-multi-stream')
 
var prettyStream = pinoms.prettyStream()
var streams = [
    {stream: fs.createWriteStream('my.log') },
    {stream: prettyStream }
]
 
var logger = pinoms(pinoms.multistream(streams))
 
logger.info("HELLO %s!", "World")
```

**abc.ts**

```
const obj = require('../logger')
const logger = obj.logger
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });
const app = express()
    .use(expressLogger)
    .use('/',express.static ({
    ...,
     setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
         res.set('set-cookie', ''), // is correct and data it hides cookie
         req.set('cookie', '') // ERROR: Cannot find name 'req'.
     }})
```

Although I am able to hide cookies in response obj request still shows cookie. How can we hide this data in output?

Answer (score 1):

the above deletes the header altogether and single sign-on shall not work. Use

```
 
var redaction = noir([
  'cookie', 'path.to.cookie'], '')

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-noir
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hiding header in req and response on express app which was generating secret info in loggers. Add a statement on express app object itself*

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  delete req.headers['cookie']; // should be lowercase
  delete req.headers['set-cookie'];
  next();
});

.use(session({
        secret: 'xxx',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false}))//the session cookie will not be set on the browser unless the session is modified
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (I needed to only delete `cookie` from headers, not the whole headers):

```
export const httpLogger = pinoHttp({
  logger,
  serializers: {
    req: pino.stdSerializers.wrapRequestSerializer(r => {
      delete r.headers['cookie']
      return r
    }),
  },
})
```